# getting undefined emoji in emoji-picker-react@4.3.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

i was implementing the emoji picker for the chat application. so when a user types a message in the input and click the emoji picker and when selecting a particular emoji i want to show the selected emoji along with the message typed by the user. instead of this when a user clicks a emoji it is showing undefined and getting some errors in the console.

```
function ChatInput() {
    const [msg,setMsg] = useState('')
    const [showEmojiPicker,setShowEmojiPicker] = useState(false);

    const handleShowEmoji = () => {
        setShowEmojiPicker(!showEmojiPicker);
    }

    const handleEmojiClick = (event,emojiObject) => {
        console.log(emojiObject);
        let message = msg;
        message += emojiObject.emoji;
        setMsg(message);
    }

  return (
    <Container>
        <div className="button-container">
            <div className="emoji">
                <BsEmojiSmileFill onClick={handleShowEmoji}/>
                {showEmojiPicker && <Picker onEmojiClick={handleEmojiClick}/> }
            </div>
        </div>
        <form className='input-container'>
            <input type='text' placeHolder='type your message here' value={msg} onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}/>
            <button className='submit'>
                <IoMdSend/>
            </button>
        </form>
    </Container>
    )
}
```

consoling the emojiObject in the console getting this below

```
PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}
```

also getting 404 error

```
cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple/img/apple/64/2695-fe0f.png:1          GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple/img/apple/64/2695-fe0f.png 404
```

my `emoji-picker-react version is 4.3.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says that **onEmojiClick** prop receives  a "**callback function that is called when an emoji is clicked. The function receives the emoji object as a parameter**."

Also, it is defined as below:

```
onEmojiClick: (emojiData: EmojiClickData, event: MouseEvent) => void
```

with the 1st argument being the emoji object and the 2nd argument being the event. In your **handleEmojiClick** you do the opposite order and that's why it returns undefined.

You could also do it like this:

```
<Picker onEmojiClick={(emojiObject)=> setMsg((prevMsg)=> prevMsg + emojiObject.emoji)}/>
```

This way you don't need "handleEmojiClick" and also correctly use the function version of updating state that is based on previous state, instead of manually doing this

`let message = msg;  message += emojiObject.emoji; setMsg(message);`

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
const onEmojiClick = (event) => {
  console.log(event.emoji);
}
```

now is with event

Answer (score 0):

after uninstalling current `emoji-picker-react` version `4.3.0` and installed previous version of `emoji-picker-react@3.5.1` fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Install emoji-picker-react@3.5.1 Version.. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
const handleEmojiClick = (event) => {
    let message = msg;
    message += event.emoji;
    setMsg(message);
    console.log(message)
}
```

You don't need second argument you can access emoji with `event.emoji`. The error in the console will not do but the code works.